# How else should I avoid using "under" at the end of the sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-ends, questions

Although it's acceptable to use prepositions at the end of the sentence, it's not favorable to grammarians or grammar teachers.

How else could I rephrase the question:

> Which license are airplan models licensed under?

Comment: Writing advice requests are off topic. Please see the [FAQ]. Thanks.

Comment: The "rule" about not ending sentences with prepositions is more of a guideline really. There is absolutely nothing wrong with "Which license are airplane models licensed under?".

Comment: The "rule" is not even a "guideline". It is completely and utterly bogus. This site is not meant for rephrasing perfectly grammatical English to satisfy random nonsensical constraints. The answer to your question, "How should I avoid this?", is "You should not avoid this" — as is well documented on this very site, on Wikipedia, on Language Log, and in countless other places.

Answer (score 5):

> Under which license are airplane models licensed?

But it would be better style if you can avoid the double use of *license*.

Comment: Since the licence gives the right to do "something", that is what should be placed in the second position. Does it give the right to manufacture, to sell, or to export?

Answer (score 1):

Or, to avoid the recommended double use of 'licence':

> **Which licence do I require for an airplane model?**
>   or
>   **Which licence do I require to do ... with an airplane model?**